# How do I find a commercial kitchen?

Tags: kitchen-safety

Was wondering if you had any go to resources for finding a commercial kitchen that is suitable for producing food for the public (licensed, insured, inspected, etc)?

I searched around this site but didn't see any good answers.  Not sure if this is too general a question for the site, please let me know if it is.

Comment: Someone else once asked me this, and I found : http://www.commercialkitchenforrent.com/ .  You can also ask churches, american legion posts and other places that have large meeting halls.  Some will only have a warming kitchen, though.  Some states or counties require them to be licensed through the local health department, so you might be able to get a list that way.

Comment: Are you asking about a place to lease or a place where you can just set up for a couple of hours and mass-produce some food?