# Commercial Kitchens in the UK

Tags: equipment, catering, kitchen

How would you find a commercial kitchen to rent in the UK? I cannot seem to find any resources for them, the only ones i've found are attached to store fronts.

Would this be a case of renting a generic workshop/manufacturing space and kitting it out yourself, or are there specific facilities for catering companies etc

I had assumed this was off topic but found this: [How do I find a commercial kitchen?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75796/how-do-i-find-a-commercial-kitchen)

while my question is similar I'm specifically asking for the UK

Comment: I'm finding plenty by just searching 'kitchen for rent'. That initially took me to this site, which seems to have listings across the UK. https://sharedining.co.uk/kitchens/

Comment: @Spagirl Looks like an answer to me!

Comment: In the US it’s really a “feast or famine” situation. Some areas have abundant options and simply googling can net results. I’ve also lived in places where the only options seem to be business incubation programs at local colleges or knowing a chef somewhere and making a personal off-hours agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of kitchen, the length of time you need it for and the number of people you are catering for etc., many community centres, pubs and large churches are willing to hire their catering facilities out and dining space as well if need be.